# flutter map problem : final Completer<Null> _readyCompleter = Completer<Null>();

Tags: flutter, dart, dictionary

**I am trying to build an app using flutter map plugin. But I got this error -**

**Before this error I added this line -**

```dart
Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getDataCollectionByLocation({
    required GeoFirePoint center,
    required double radius,
    required String field,
  }) {
    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = _geo
        .collection(collectionRef: ref)
        .within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field);
    return stream;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you added `import 'dart:async';`?

Comment: I have many files which uses flutter map. In which file I will have to add dart async? I have added it on the file where I used that function.

Comment: You must add `import 'dart:async;'` in any file that uses `Stream` and `Completer`.